# TYPO3 add section to link in TMENU

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I try to build a simple menu where the field "subtitle" (if set) from the page is added as anchor to the link

```
MAINMENU2 = HMENU
MAINMENU2 {
    special = directory
    special.value = 1

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="menu">|</ul>
        noBlur = 1
        NO = 1
        NO.stdWrap.typolink.section.field = subtitle
    }
}
```

output: `<a href="/page1">Page XY</a>`
expected: `<a href="/page1#101">Page XY</a>`

How must the TypoScript look like to get this work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the automatic link building of TMENU with `doNotLinkIt` and then build the complete link with `typolink`:

```
NO {
  doNotLinkIt = 1
  stdWrap.typolink {
    parameter.field = uid
    section.field = subtitle
  }
}
```